# Como devolver un objeto modificado desde otra activity

Tags: java, android, poo, listview, android-intent

Antes que nada aclarar que estoy empezando con Android y desconozco si estoy realizando algo mal o si hay otros métodos para realizar x cosas.

En mi MainActivity tengo una lista con objetos de una clase.
Voy a poner ejemplos en los códigos ya que tengo una clase más extensa.

Tengo 2 preguntas similares:

1) Quiero mandar la persona en la que haga click del ListView(lista de objetos persona) a otro Activity. En el otro Activity modifico la persona y quiero devolverla a la lista del MainActivity con los atributos modificados.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Lista de personas
     private List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

     private Persona p1 = new Persona("Pepe", "Gomez", 43);
     private Persona p2 = new Persona("Pepa", "Serrano", 42);

     private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        personas.add(p1);
        personas.add(p2);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        /* Aqui es donde tengo el problema, ya que quiero modificar
        /* la persona en la que hago click en el list*/
        Bundle objetoRecibido = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(objetoRecibido != null){
            Persona p3 = (Persona) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("datosModificados");
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Persona> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Persona>(this, R.layout.listview_items, personas);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putSerializable("persona", personas.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Persona persona = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        Bundle objetoRecibido = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(objetoRecibido != null){
            persona = (Persona) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("persona");
            /* Aquí iría el formulario pero para no extender el código lo pongo con sets */
            persona.setNombre("NombreModificado");
            persona.setApellido("ApellidoModificado");
            persona.setEdad(18);
        }
    }

    public void botonMainActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putSerializable("datosModificados", persona);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

2) Como he dicho, es similar, la cosa es que quiero hacer las dos cosas a la vez. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es añadir personas al ListView(lista de objetos persona) del MainActivity desde la otra Activity2.
Supongamos el siguiente codigo:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Lista de personas
     private List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

     private Persona p1 = new Persona("Pepe", "Gomez", 43);
     private Persona p2 = new Persona("Pepa", "Serrano", 42);

     private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        personas.add(p1);
        personas.add(p2);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        /* Aquí es donde vuelvo a tener el problema*/
        Bundle objetoRecibido = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(objetoRecibido != null){
            Persona p3 = (Persona) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("datosModificados");
            Persona p4 = (Persona) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("añadirPersona");
            personas.add(p4);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Persona> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Persona>(this, R.layout.listview_items, personas);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putSerializable("persona", personas.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void añadirPersona(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Activity 2

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Persona persona = null;
    private Persona persona2 = new Persona("Persona", "Añadida", 30);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        Bundle objetoRecibido = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(objetoRecibido != null){
            persona = (Persona) objetoRecibido.getSerializable("persona");
            /* Aquí iría el formulario pero para no extender el código lo pongo con sets */
            persona.setNombre("NombreModificado");
            persona.setApellido("ApellidoModificado");
            persona.setEdad(18);
        }
    }

    public void botonMainActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();

        bundle.putSerializable("datosModificados", persona);
        bundle2.putSerializable("añadirPersona", persona2);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.putExtras(bundle2);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme. Disculpad si hay algún error en los códigos, llevo demasiadas horas. Espero que se entienda lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Hola por lo que veo ya manejas el pasaje de parametros de un activity al siguiente. Lo que necesitas ahora es lograr que los activities entreguen una respuesta.

Explico como seria la secuencia y despues dejo un ejemplo simple:

Supongamos un ActivityPersonas con una lista de personas y un ActivityEditaPersona que te permite editar los campos de euna persona de la lista del primer Activity. La secuencia deberia ser la siguiente:

1. En el ActivityPersonas se selecciona una persona
2. Se crea el Intent del AcitivityEditaPersona con los parametros de la persona
3. Se ejecuta el startActivityForResult() del ActivityEditaPersona
4. Se editan los valores de la persona
5. Se crea el Result del con los valores de la persona
6. Se ejecuta el finish() del ActivityEditaPersona, volviendo a ActivityPersonas
7. Se atrapa el resultado devuelto por el ActivityEditaPersona.

Y ahora un pequeño ejemplo del codigo:

En el ActivityPersona:

```
int CODIGO_DE_RESULTADO = 1

private void onPersonaSeleccionada(){
  Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityPersonas.this, ActivityEditaPersona.class);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

  bundle.putSerializable("persona", personas.get(position));
  intent.putExtras(bundle);

  //Esto ejecuta al activity pero quedamos a la espera de que devuelva un resultado
  startActivityForResult(intent, CODIGO_DE_RESULTADO);
}

//Esto se ejecutara cuando el Activity lanzado con startActivityForResult termine
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  //Validamos que el resultado sea del activity que lanzamos y que sea OK
  if (requestCode == CODIGO_DE_RESULTADO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     String nombre = data.getStringExtra("nombre");
     String apellido = data.getStringExtra("apellido");
     //Estos son los datos modificados por el ActivityEditaPersona, recuperados en la misma instancia del ActivityPersonas que lo ejecuto
  }
}
```

En el ActityEditaPersona:

```
private void onTerminarEdicion(){
   //Creamos el intent con los datos editados
   Intent data = new Intent();
   data.putExtra("nombre", nombreEditado);
   data.putExtra("apellido", apellidoEditado);

   //Indicamos que los datos son el resultado del Activity
   setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
   //Terminamos el activity para volver al Activity anterior
   finish();
}
```

Una vez que tengas los datos atrapados en el activity original podes hacer el manejo que necesites. Usa esta tecnica siempre que necesites abrir un activity que pretenda devolver datos al activity que lo ejecuto.

Comment: He estado probando tu solución y quería comentarte como ha ido. He descubierto que CODIGO_DE_RESULTADO debe ser int, por lo demás esta bien. Me ha funcionado hasta que he introducido un RecyclerView, con su Adaptador. Al poner en el Adaptador en onBindViewHolder he puesto un setOnClickListener (para enviar los datos cuando de click en algún elemento de la lista) y allí no puedo realizar el startActivityForResult. ¿Sabes si hay alguna manera de usarlo allí? ¿O se debe usar otro método? Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Gracias Treblack ahí lo cambie a int. Si no te anda el starActivityForResult desde el click puede ser porque no estas dentro del Activity sino del holder o el adapter (nose donde habras puesto el codigo), asegurate de que el onClick del holder retorne por un callback al activity para que puedas manejar la navegacion, sino no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer recomendaria fuese realizado utilizando [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) de manera que puedas obtener modificar y guardar los datos donde necesites, sin estar usando `Bundles` o `intent.putExtras`, usando esta libreria y `SharedPreferences` te facilitas mucho el trabajo, ejemplo:

Creas 2 metodos estaticos para guardar y obtener la data del preference:

```
private static final String PREFERENCES = "preferences";

public static void SetStringValue(Context context, String key, String save) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, save);
        editor.apply();
    }

public static String GetStringValue(Context context, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(key, null);
    }
```

Bien una vez creado esto, agregamos la repectiva libreria al gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

Sincronizamos y luego solo queda implementar lo que se quiere guardar y lo que se quiere obtener segun se necesite. Como estas usando una lista es importante que pases la posicion del item que vas a modificar, ya que de esto depende que se almacene la data donde corresponda. Teniendo esto en cuenta nos quedaria implementar el guardado de la informacion asi:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();

// llenas la lista con los objetos que necesites
  ....
  ....
       //

//Luego guardas asi
SetStringValue(context, "LISTA", gson.toJson(personas));
```

De esta manera estas convirtiendo la lista "personas" en un string gracias a la libreria Gson y guardando esta lista en el preference con el key "LISTA", ya teniendola guardada solo queda obtenerla donde se necesite, y esto se logra de la siguiente forma:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Personas>>() {}.getType());
List<Personas> listadepersonas = new ArrayList<>();

listadepersonas = gson.fromJson(GetStringValue(context, "LISTA"), collectionType);
```

De esta forma obtienes la lista guardada en el preference, y la almacenas en "listadepersonas", ahora solo queda obtener los datos de tu lista y setearlos donde necesitas que se haga, como quieres modificar una posicion de esta lista, como mencione anteriormente, obtienes los valores del objeto de la lista segun la posicion que pases de tu adaptador (ListView o RecyclerView) los cambias, lo seteas en la esa posicion de la lista y vuelves a guardar la lista en el preference asi:

```
SetStringValue(context, "LISTA", gson.toJson(personas));
```

De esta manera tendras mejor manejo de la data de la lista en todo el codigo y no tienes que escribir tantas lineas, cada vez que necesites modificar valores, obtienes, modificas la posicion y vuelves a guardar y listo.

Por ultimo, si quieres guardar un solo objeto usando Gson y no una lista, la sintaxis seria asi:

**GUARDAR:**

```
SetStringValue(context, "OBJETO" , gson.toJson(Persona));
```

**OBTENER:**

```
private Persona persona;

persona = gson.fromJson(GetStringValue(context, "OBJETO"), Persona.class);
```

Y el mismo procedimiento, obtienes, modificas y vuelves a guardar. Espero te funcione.